# Tensorflow model with custom loss function gets no training done

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I created a custom loss function as below:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)

    mask = K.sign(y_true) * K.sign(y_pred)
    mask = ((mask * -1) + 1) / 2
    losses = K.abs(y_true * mask)

    return K.sum(losses)
```

However, when I try to train the model using this loss function, I get no training done.
The model works normally with other loss functions such as mse and mae, and I've tried all learning rates and model complexities.

Below is how I know no training is being done.

```
model = get_compiled_model()
print(model.predict(train_x)[:10])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, verbose=1)
print(model.predict(train_x)[:10])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, verbose=1)
print(model.predict(train_x)[:10])
```

```
[[0.19206487]
 [0.19201839]
 [0.19199933]
 [0.19199185]
 [0.19206186]
 [0.19208357]
 [0.1920282 ]
 [0.19203594]
 [0.1919941 ]
 [0.19202243]]
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0179
[[0.19206487]
 [0.19201839]
 [0.19199933]
 [0.19199185]
 [0.19206186]
 [0.19208357]
 [0.1920282 ]
 [0.19203594]
 [0.1919941 ]
 [0.19202243]]
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 951us/step - loss: 0.0179
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0179
[[0.19206487]
 [0.19201839]
 [0.19199933]
 [0.19199185]
 [0.19206186]
 [0.19208357]
 [0.1920282 ]
 [0.19203594]
 [0.1919941 ]
 [0.19202243]]
```

The 2d array in the code above is the first 10 predictions of the model, and it does not change in the slightest even with 5 epochs of training.

My intuition tells me something is wrong with the loss function, but I have no idea what.

The model looks like as follows

```
def get_compiled_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=2*training_size+1, activation='softmax'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
  ])

  opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                loss=custom_loss,
                metrics=[])
  return model
```

Comment: It could resolve to a minimum at a trivial solution. Did you check the predictions before you did any training?

Comment: Ah thats an interesting point. I’ll check on that asap.

Comment: Just tired it, and the predictions stay the same. It doesn't seem to be a problem due to quick resolution.

Comment: You'll probably have to include more information then. Maybe even a model, and the setup you're using to train. Which optimizer, and what is the learning rate?

Comment: What do you mean by model? I'm using a feedforward neural net with multiple layers, learning rates all tried in the range of 1e-2 to 1e-6, optimizer is Adam. What I don't get is that since there is a loss being produced (0.0179), by definition the model should be backpropagating and updating the weights, which it isn't.

Comment: And the thing is that the model is successfully updating the weights through other loss functions such as mse and mae.

Comment: Your "feedforward neural net" is a model. "...by definition the model should be backpropagating and updating the weights" That is not necessarily true. The loss function needs to change when the weights are changing. Quite honestly, I don't understand how this loss function relates to your prediction. You claim to be making 10 predictions, so that means your output has a single value?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. "You'll probably have to include more information then" I thought this meant include more dimensions to the input to the model as information. My bad I will edit the question to include more information as you said.

Comment: The only way you're using pred value is through a 'K.sign' which is going to be 1, 0, -1. It looks like that will make for really poor derivatives.

Comment: Aha I think that solved it. I tried involving the pred value more in the loss function and the loss is decreasing (tho only by the smallest figures...). Thanks for sticking with me, I actually learned a lot just talking to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with some fake data using your model and loss function, and I wanted to [check the derivatives](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#gradients_with_respect_to_a_model).

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    m = get_compiled_model()
    x = numpy.random.random( (1000, 21))
    x = numpy.array(x, dtype="float32")
    exp_y = numpy.random.random( (1000, 1))
    exp_y = (exp_y>0.5)*1.0 
    
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = m(x)
        loss = custom_loss(y, exp_y)
        #loss = keras.losses.mse(y, exp_y)
        grad = tape.gradient(loss, m.trainable_variables)
        for var, g in zip(m.trainable_variables, grad):
            print(f'{var.name}, shape: {K.sum(g*g)}')
```

For the mse loss function:

> dense/kernel:0, shape: 2817.013671875
> dense/bias:0, shape: 530.52197265625
> dense_1/kernel:0, shape: 3826.3974609375
> dense_1/bias:0, shape: 25160.9375
> dense_2/kernel:0, shape: 125238.34375
> dense_2/bias:0, shape: 1241268.5

For the custom loss function

> dense/kernel:0, shape: 34.87071228027344
> dense/bias:0, shape: 6.609962463378906
> dense_1/kernel:0, shape: 107.27591705322266
> dense_1/bias:0, shape: 824.83740234375
> dense_2/kernel:0, shape: 5944.91796875
> dense_2/bias:0, shape: 59201.58203125

We can see that the sum of derivatives are orders of magnitude different. Even with this random data, the MSE loss function will cause the output of the model to change over time.

This might only be the case for the fake data I made.